# Applying style to binding formula

Tags: html, extjs, data-binding

I'm trying to apply style to a bound formula in a ViewModel.

My ViewModel is:

```
viewModel: {
                formulas: {
                    firstTestStoreRecord: {
                        bind: '{testStore}',
                        get: function(testStore) {
                            return testStore.getAt(0);
                        }
                    }
                },
                stores:{
                    testStore: {
                        //fields: [{ name: 'test', type: 'string' }],
                        data: [{
                            test: 'Foo',
                            style: {
                                'font-size': '22px',
                                'color':'red',
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            },
```

And my reference to the bound formula is:

```
items: [{
                xtype: 'form',
                title: 'Bound form',
                flex: 1,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'label',
                    bind: {
                        html: '<b>{firstTestStoreRecord.test}</b>',
                        bodyStyle: '{style}'
                    }
                }]
            }]
```

Here is a Fiddle of what I am trying: [Bind store from a ViewModel to an xtype label with style](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/25f7&view/editor). I am trying to change the font style in the html, but it is NOT working. I am using this as a reference: [How-to-bind-to-style-and-or-html-property](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?289227-How-to-bind-to-style-and-or-html-property)

Comment: The first thing I see is that your html is bound to `firstTestStoreRecord.test`, but your style is *NOT* bound to `firstTestStoreRecord.style`.

Comment: Plus, a label has no `bodyStyle`, nor does it have a `style` config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that are wrong:

- A label does not have a `style`, let alone a `bodyStyle` config. If you want to style, you have to use inline HTML on the label or take a container.
- Your binding of the style is not against the record (`firstTestStoreRecord`).

Corrected and working code:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'container',
    bind: {
        html: '<b>{firstTestStoreRecord.test}</b>',
        style: '{firstTestStoreRecord.style}'
    }
}]
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! Now to just figure out how to use this in a store with a model using an AJAX proxy.